# How to display tags on pop up? laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple page table in which I am displaying page list, visual looks like this.

[image]

**Expected result :**

Now  I want  when a user clicks view tags it should display the tags related to that page

eg if a user clicks view tag on row one with  ID 6 it should display tag `tes1` in a pop up modal if a user clicks view tag on row one with  ID 7 it should display a tag named `test2` in a pop up modal

**Problem:**

Now when user clicks a button view tags in either row I get the following result

[image]

Here is how I display tags in a pop up when user clicks view tags button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    {{ __('view tags') }}
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tag List</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            name
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($page->tags as $tag)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ $tag->tag->id }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $tag->tag->name }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my repository :**  [my demo repository](https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/resources/views/pages/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating your modal and button code in foreach loop?

If so - I'm not saying it is the perfect solution, but it works. What I think may be the problem is that your model opening button property data-target is the exact same for every single one. Also the modal id is the same for every single row.

So everytime you click open modal button, it opens up the first modal, which is the one in your picture.

What I would suggest doing is either making 1 modal, which contents are being changed with JavaScript when button is clicked.

If you don't wanna use JavaScript, you should add unique values to your modal id and button data-target.
**Here is example for button:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$page->id}}">
{{ __('view tags') }}

</button>
```

**Example for modals first row:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$page->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Hi, Now I am getiing empyt list ?  :(

Comment: In your repository, you accidentally put space between examplemodal and {{$page->id}}

Also, there is no unique identifier on the button.

I'll post working example

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#exampleModal{{$page->id}}">

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$page->id}} " tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Add the page id to button data-target attribute too, then it will work.

Comment: Like so:
data-target="#exampleModal{{$page->id}}"

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is it always shows first modal.

**Here is the solution:-**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-{{ PageID }}">
        {{ __('view tags') }}
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
@foreach ($pages as $page)
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-{{ $page->ID }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tag List</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <th>
                                ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                name
                            </th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($page->tags as $tag)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $tag->tag->id }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $tag->tag->name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Another solution**

Clicking on View tag button call ajax and update data in modal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunatelly I am getting empty list now :(

Comment: Here is my repository if you want to check my code https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/resources/views/pages/index.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

Pass Your Page Id into your modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$page->id}}">
    {{ __('view tags') }}
</button>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$page->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tag List</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            name
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($page->tags as $tag)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ $tag->tag->id }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $tag->tag->name }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunatelly I am getting empty list now :(